# Configuring static files settings for Docker on Amazon Linux 2 ends with the error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

When doing any kind of attempts for `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles` it just doesn't work. Every time I receive errors about invalid option specification. All the rest of ebextensions settings work like a charm.

Example snippet that I try:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /stylesheets: public/stylesheets
    /fonts: public/fonts
    /html: public/html
```

Error on `eb deploy`:

```
2021-04-09 08:12:02    ERROR   "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
2021-04-09 08:12:02    ERROR   Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles', OptionName: '/stylesheets'): Unknown configuration setting.
...
```

Running EB platform with Docker on 64bit Amazon Linux 2, version 3.2.6. I start suspecting this `staticfiles` spec is unsupported on this platform for any reason but I crawled through AWS EB documentation seeking for any hints with no success. Interestingly, there is no static files section in the web console UI either.

I tried every configuration flavors - trailing slashes, quotation, different sets of those paths... Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`staticfiles` are **not supported** for Docker platforms. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html):

> Elastic Beanstalk supports configuring the proxy to serve static files on most platform branches based on Amazon Linux 2. The one **exception is Docker**.

Comment: @RemigiuszOrłowski No problem. Glad I could help.